# Is it possible to convert a field of varchar(32) to BLOB in Firebird database

Tags: sql, utf-8, firebird

I would like to keep data which is already saved into a Table field varchar(32) and to convert it to BLOB in Firebird database. 
I am using a software: IBExpert ....
If it is possible, how to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's consider you have table TEST with one column NAME:

```
create table test (name varchar(32));
insert into test values('test1');
insert into test values('test2');
insert into test values('test3');
commit;
select * from test;
```

It is possible to change the column from varchar to BLOB by the following script:

```
alter table test add name_blob blob;
update test set name_blob = name;
commit;
alter table test drop name;
alter table test alter column name_blob to name;
commit;
select * from test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in `IBExpert` it easy to do with `Firebird 2.1` and `Firebird 2.5` via direct modifications of system tables (this "obsolete" method was prohibited in `Firebird 3` but nothing was introduced to replace it).

This works in both directions, `VARCHAR` to `BLOB` and `BLOB` to `VARCHAR`.

You have to have a `DOMAIN` - that is, a named data type, in SQL, and that domain should be of `BLOB` type - then `IBExpert` itself would issue the command, that `Firebird 2.x` executes, if you set Firebird 2.x in database options.

If you don't have `IB Expert` then the following command you have to issue:

```
CREATE DOMAIN T_TEXT_BLOB AS   -- prerequisite
BLOB SUB_TYPE 1; 

update RDB$RELATION_FIELDS     -- the very action
set RDB$FIELD_SOURCE = 'T_TEXT_BLOB'  
   /* the name of the blob domain to be set as the field's new data type */
where RDB$FIELD_SOURCE = '.....' /* name of the column */
  and RDB$RELATION_NAME = '....' /* name of the table */
```

See also:

- https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-domn.html
- https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx04-relfields.html

When you create a column or change its datatype without explicitly naming the type (like just `varchar(10)`) then under the hood Firebird creates automatically-managed one-per-column user domains with names like `RDB$12345`, so while you can do that too, perhaps having an explicit named `domain` would be more practical and more safe.

This method however fails on Firebird 3, where you do have to copy the whole table, as shown by Maxim above.

- http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-6052

FB devs warn about some "bugs" and "it never worked properly" however refuse to give details.

---

**UPDATE** I finally managed to reproduce the bug mentioned in the tracker.

At least in Firebird 2.1 reference counting is broken w.r.t. BLOB payloads.
So the trick seems to be to instantly re-write implicit blobs into explicit, tricking Firebird to think we supplied **new content** for all the BLOB values.

Assuming the names from Maxim's answer above...

**To trigger and demonstrate the bug** take the "vanilla" `VarChar` database, apply the conversion described above, and issue the following commands:

- `update test set name = name` -- trying to force data conversion, but instead forcing Firebird reference counting bug
- `select cast( name as VarChar(200) ) from test` - or actually any command that would try to actually read the field contents - any such attempt would be shot down with the infamous `invalid BLOB ID` Firebird error.

**To work around the bug** we must prevent Firebird from (broken) reference counting. So, we must do a fake update, invoking expression evaluator, so that Firebird optimizer would loose track of value sources and would fail to realize the data was not really changed.

- `update test set name = '' || name || ''` -- really forcing data over-writing and conversion, bypassing BLOB reference counting.
- `select cast( name as VarChar(200) ) from test` - now works like a charm (albeit 200 was too short a string and you would be stuck with "overflow" error

The `update` command can be any other triggering expression evaluator, for example  `update test set name = cast( name as VarChar( NNN ) )` - but you would need to devise large enough NNN for specific column of specific table. So, string concatenations with empty string is universal and does the work, at least on Firebird 2.1.

---

The above stands for Firebird 2.1.7 Win32. I did not manage to trigger "invalid BLOB id" with Firebird 2.5.8 Win64 - it "just worked".
At least using the single-connection schema update script, which is anyway the intended way to do database upgrades. 
Maybe if I would do schema upgrades while simultaneously there would be users actively working - the FB 2.5 would get broken too, don't know.

Whether to use this shortcut risky way disregarding FB developers' hints, or to use "official" Maxim's answer, possibly dismounting and then re-creating half the database which happened to have "dependencies" upon the field to be dropped, stays up to the reader.